# What relative path do I need to use in my Java Project

Tags: java, path, relative-path

I have a structure like:

```
src 
  -|com 
       -|company 
               -|Core --> JAVA class 
  -|rules --> text files
```

Inside Core is a Java Class that uses:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName)));
```

But I cannot figure out what relative path to use. Now I use:

```
"..\\..\\..\\..\\rules\\rule1.txt"
```

I also tried:

```
"../../../../rules/rule1.txt"
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't work that way. Relative paths are relative to the *working directory* of the current application, **not** the directory of the class. If you want to find out what your current working directory is, use `System.getProperty("user.dir")`.

A better way is to add the rules directory to the classpath and then use [`Class#getResourceAsStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

---

An alternative would be to set the path to the rules directory somehow else: You could provide a command line option if that is feasible or set some system property (e.g. `java -Drules.path=/path/to/rules ...` and later read via `System.getProperty("rules.path")`).

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.dir")` prints out the `root directory` of the `eclipse installation` on my machine, which is useless.  It would be helpful to get the `root directory` of the `eclipse project`.

Comment: @CodeMed Try changing the working directory in the "Arguments" tab of the run configuration.

Comment: +1 Thank you.  That gets it to work when I do `Run As..Run on Server` in eclipse.  But will the working directory setting be migrated into the war file when I compile the app later?

Comment: @CodeMed No, you cannot rely on the current working directory in a servlet environment. There are other solutions such as working with the servlet context or setting properties. You should look for other questions or ask one yourself. The topic is getting a bit out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

It depends where you are launching from, not on the package structure of your java classes. As @EJP points out there are other APIs that do reflect your package structure.

One trick I have used in the past is to have a line of code create a file "SomeSillyName.txt". And see where that actually pops up.

My guess is that you might be launching from src, and so a simple "rules/rule1.txt" would work.

Answer (score 2):

The current directory when executing has nothing to do with what package the current class is in. It doesn't change.

If your file is distributed with the application, use Class.getResourceAsStream().

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an IDE like Eclipse the working directory is by default the projects root folder. So `src/rules/rule1.txt` should work. (Or I misunderstood your folder structure.)